# Question about "this" in jQuery.on() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this, event-binding

Event binding is a common pattern in JS, and here is one way to do it from a code I read: `$('#toggle-all').on('change', this.toggleAll.bind(this));`

In this case, there is an input with id *toggle-all*, which runs the `this.toggleAll` method when clicked.

However, even without binding, eg `$('#toggle-all').on('change', this.toggleAll);` the `toggleAll` method can still run, although it hits an error halfway through the method. But it still runs.

However, for another method: `todoLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton());`

`this.createDeleteButton()` **does not run at all** if I do not bind it. What is the difference between the two examples? I know one is passing in a (callback) function as a parameter, and the other is directly running the method. But the second example **does not run at all without binding** while the `this.toggleAll` method runs even without binding. Why is this so?

```
var App = {
    bindEvents: function () {
        $('#toggle-all').on('change', this.toggleAll); // without binding
    }, 

    toggleAll: function (e) {
        console.log(this); // prints jQuery object which is the input #toggle-all
        var isChecked = $(e.target).prop('checked');

        // error from this line onward, which is expected.
        this.todos.forEach(function (todo) { // "this" is the input element, hence error
           todo.completed = isChecked;
        });

       this.render();
    }
};
```

For the second option, here is the code:

```
var view = {
  displayTodos: function() {
    var todosUl = document.querySelector('ul');
    todosUl.innerHTML = '';

    todoList.todos.forEach(function(todo, position) {
      var todoLi = document.createElement('li');
      var todoTextWithCompletion = '';

      if (todo.completed === true) {
        todoTextWithCompletion = '(x) ' + todo.todoText;
      } else {
        todoTextWithCompletion = '( ) ' + todo.todoText;
      }

      todoLi.id = position;
      todoLi.textContent = todoTextWithCompletion;
      todoLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton());
      todosUl.appendChild(todoLi);
    }, this); // binding "this". If I remove it, the error I get in the console is: client.js:90 Uncaught TypeError: this.createDeleteButton is not a function
  },

  // creates a delete button beside every li element in the DOM.
  createDeleteButton: function() {
    console.log(this);
    var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
    deleteButton.className = 'deleteButton';
    return deleteButton;
  },
```

Main question:  Why is it that a method can be run without binding (in the first case). But in the second case, it cannot be run at all without binding? 
AKA
Why does jQuery.on() accept the un-binded this.toggleAll, but appendChild is not able to accept the un-binded this.createDeleteButton()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Basically, the problem is that the value of `this` could change depending on how it's executed. Binding a function sets the value of `this` inside it.

Comment: I think my question was more of: Why is it that a method can be run without binding (in the first case). But in the second case, it cannot be run at all without binding?

Comment: You said your first option *has an error*. That doesn't mean it "runs". And you haven't supplied any details about the second option.

Comment: Ah yes, I apologize. The first option does execute the console.log(this) line (hence the method "runs"), but it faces an error when trying to access this.todos.forEach, because "this" has not been binded.

Comment: Correct. However, we have no way of knowing why your second option doesn't work without any details about it.

Comment: Actually 'this' is a special keyword inside each function and its value only depends on how the function was called, not how/when/where it was defined.

Comment: Code need not be bolded.

Comment: @freedomn-m I shall add the scope/context of first option. But I have little to no interest in "bind", I am curious as to why the method runs (the first few lines at least), *without* bind.

Comment: In summary: because jquery is calling `.bind` (or `.call`) for you

Comment: @freedomn-m HAHA my guess was something along those lines too. Not very inclined to look into how the .on() method is executed. Shall just take that as an answer then.

Comment: Did you check you browser's console for error messages? These would probably be informative for you. `this` in `forEach()` callback is `globalThis` (i.e `window` in browser) except if you did pass the `thisArg` second argument, or somehow bound the callback. So when the engine encounters `this.createDeleteButton()` it's actually `window.createDeleteButton` that gets called, and I guess there is no such method available => You must have an Error message along the lines of *"Uncaught TypeError: this.createDeleteButton is not a function"*.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, very perceptive. That is exactly what happened. I guess my overall question is: why does jQuery.on() accept the un-binded this.toggleAll, but appendChild is not able to accept the un-binded this.createDeleteButton()

Comment: But `jquery.on` has nothing to do with the problem here. You are merely doing `var mycallback = this.toggleAll; $('#toggle-all').on('change', mycallback)`. In this scope `this` is just your `App` object. nothing fancy.

Comment: Hmm... but why doesn't the unbinded this.createDeleteButton() work then? I feel like you are on the verge of an answer though.

Comment: Now with context: `this.createDeleteButton()` doesn't work because *it's inside another function*. Therefore `this` refers to the callback given to `forEach` - the `function(todo, position) { }`, and NOT to `view`. If you bind the callback, then it uses the correct `this`. This is exactly the same issue you get when you call `this.todos` where `this` doesn't have a `todos` property, only in this case it doesn't have a `createDeleteButton` property. So, again I refer you to the dupe.

Comment: Mhaaa... What do you not understand? In the second case, you are **in the forEach callback**. There `this` is `window`.  In the first case, you are **in `App.bindEvents`**, `this` is `App`.

Comment: Okay, I have tried adding this line: 
printOne: function() {
    console.log("1"); 
    console.log(this); // window object
  }, 
and subsequently: 
todos.forEach(this.printOne);

and it works. This is for case 2. 
I kind of get it now. Thank you! @Kaiido